# Changing Text of HTML Button Using Outside JS Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my main HTML file, I create a variable using this script:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Creation of answerjson not shown
var choiceOne = answerjson[0].choice;

});
```

Later in my HTML, I create a button within a div using this code:

```
   <div id= "one"><button class="button" id = "b1"></button></div>
```

How can I display the value of choiceOne as the label on button b1? I've searched online, but only found answers to this problem when the button is not in a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var choiceOne = "Some Text";

// jQuery 
$("#b1").text(choiceOne);

// Regular JavaScript
document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = choiceOne;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"><button class="button" id="b1"></button></div>
<div id="two"><button class="button" id="b2"></button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('#b1').html(choiceOne);
```

but you need to do this in

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

so you are sure all of the DOM is ready and loaded ... not sooner

Answer (score 0):

Access the button from inside your javascript and change the text on it using the following command:

```
document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = choiceOne;
```

This is in regular JS. You can also use JQuery to select the container.